# Puppeteer Select Link

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer, google-chrome-headless

I want to click on a link in a html page, which contains following snippet:

```
<p>Die maximale Trefferanzahl von 200 wurde überschritten.
  <a href="/rp_web/search.do?doppelt">Verdoppeln Sie hier  Suchergebnislimit.</a>
</p>
```

I'm setting some filters before and then I am loading the page, which loads the page I need. On that resulting page, I want to click on the link as seen in the html snippet. 
The js I'm trying to use is this one

```
await Promise.all([
    page.click('input#landNW'), // set a filter
    page.click('input[type=submit]'), // submit the form
    page.waitForNavigation(), // wait for the page to load
    page.click('p a'), // not working: double the search results
    page.waitForNavigation() // not working: waiting for the page to reload
]).catch(e => console.log(e)); // no error
```

I am pretty sure the `page.click('p a')` is working properly, because in the console of my chrome browser I can do `document.querySelector("p a").click()`, which then reloads the page as expected.

I have also tried to select the url by using the href attr, e.g. with `page.click('a[href="/rp_web/search.do?doppelt"]')`, but I got an error:
`No node found for selector: a[href="/rp_web/search.do?doppelt"]`.

How can I accomplish what I expect to happen?

**EDIT** You can find the complete repo here: [bitbucket/ytNeskews](https://bitbucket.org/ytNeskews/puppeteer-attempt/src/master/src/index.js)

Comment: Great question — clear problem statement, code sample included — it does show effort made!

Comment: And an answer as clear and informative as yours is always pleasant!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are lots of reports about `page.click` not working and in your case it indeed won't work for some reason. Luckily we can do everything with the help of a good old `page.evaluate` (or `page.$eval`): here I'm clicking the link manually in the browser context:

```
const puppeteer  = require ('puppeteer');
(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless : false });
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('https://www.handelsregister.de/rp_web/mask.do?Typ=e');

    await Promise.all([
        page.click('input#landNW'), // set a filter
        page.click('input[type=submit]'), // submit the form
        page.waitForNavigation(), // wait for the page to load
    ]).catch(e => console.log(e));

    // Print the number of allowed results (must be 200)
    console.log(await page.$eval('#inhalt p', el => el.textContent.match(/\d+ hits/)[0]));

    await Promise.all([
         // Manual clicking of the link
         page.$eval('p a', el => el.click()),
         page.waitForNavigation()
    ]).catch(e => console.log(e));

    // Print the number of allowed results (must be 400 now)
    console.log(await page.$eval('#inhalt p', el => el.textContent.match(/\d+ hits/)[0]));

    await browser.close();
})();
```

Results:

> 200 hits
>   400 hits

Also not that you should wait only for one page navigation at once. And one more note if I may — it is much more convenient to write such scripts with Chromium visible ({headless : false}).

Answer (score 2):

The code seems fine and I think puppeteer is actually attempting the click. However, it's not clicking the link in question.

Change the viewport by

```
await page.setViewport({width: 1366, height: 768})
```

and your code seems to work. Have notified the puppeteer team about this possible bug.

Comment: Interesting! Is it confirmed that `page.click` only works inside of the visible area? Does the OP's code work for you with only viewport enlarged? (It won't for me)

Comment: Yes, it works for me in the enlarged viewport. I can see the request triggered

Comment: Page.click is currently more like click at this point in the page, which is the center of the element. Hence the change in viewport seems to make a difference.

Comment: And all actions in one Promise.all wrapper - do they work too? Do you reach 400 hits limit?

Comment: So I refactored that to only wrap one request with its waitForNavigation like you have before I started. Sorry, I didn't mention that in my response

Comment: The bug has been confirmed [here](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/2804).