# Puppeteer not waiting for timeout

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I have a page with a list of company names. This list is initially limited by 200 results, but there is a link to double that limit. With every click the loading time rises up to a few minutes.

I am using following code.

```
/**
 * @param {object} page - a puppeteer page object
 * @param {number} by - how many times I need to click on the link
 */
async function multiply(page, by = 5) {
    for (let i = 0; i < by; i++) {
        await Promise.all([
            // Manual clicking of the link
            page.$eval('p a', el => el.click()),

            // set a timeout of 8 minutes
            page.waitForNavigation(480000) 
        ]).catch(e => console.log(e));
    }
}
```

I expect a timeout of 8 minutes, but I get the follwing error:

```
Error: Navigation Timeout Exceeded: 30000ms exceeded
```

I have also tried to wait for Navigation **before** clicking on the link. Then I tried to manually wait for a defined timeout with `page.waitFor(i ** 2 * 10000)` - but no luck. Waiting for the selector to be in the html did not work either.

I am not using `page.click('p a')`, because it is confirmed as a bug [here](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/2798).

You may wanna have a look at another  [already-solved question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51011466/puppeteer-select-link) to my project, which describes my use case little bit more in detail.

If you want to have a closer look, you can clone the complete repo by clicking on [bitbucket.org/ytNewskews](https://bitbucket.org/ytNeskews/puppeteer-attempt/src/295cda1a633cf667bc914ae9376814b6e6a0c4dc/src/multiply.js?at=feature%2Finit_tests).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`page.waitForNavigation(options)` expects an Object with properties like this:

```
   // set a timeout of 8 minutes
   page.waitForNavigation({timeout: 480000})
```

The default is 30000ms. The default value can be changed by using the page.setDefaultNavigationTimeout(timeout) method.

From: [Puppeteer API](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v10.4.0&show=api-pagewaitfornavigationoptions)

Comment: One of those days :D